# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

Mal funcionamiento o mala sintaxis del evento "onclick" sobre elementos del HTML creados en una función del DOM.

¿A qué se debe este error?

```
animales.js:70 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

La línea 70 es la siguiente:

```
document.getElementById("cerdo").onclick = sonidoCerdo;
```

Código completo.

**Código HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <title>Animales!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/estilo.css"/>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/animales.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Código Javascript/DOM:**

```
/*Exclusivamente usar funciones DOM.*/

/*Registro un evento para cuando termine de cargarse el documento se cargen los eventos necesarios.*/
window.onload = crearTabla;

/*Array donde estan definidos los nombres de los animales.*/
var animales = ["cerdo", "gato", "perro", "vaca"];

/*Exclusivamente con DOM, crear una tabla 2x2 (4 elementos-casillas).*/
function crearTabla() {
    //Obtener la referencia del elemento body.
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    //Creamos el elemento/objeto que deseamos: <div>.
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    //Asignamos un id al div creado.
    div.setAttribute("id", "animales");
    //Agregamos al body el div.
    body.appendChild(div);

    //Crea un elemento <table> y un elemento <tbody>.
    var tabla = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    //Crea las celdas. 
    var contador = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        var hilera = document.createElement("tr"); 
        for (var j=0; j<2; j++) {
            //Creamos el elemento <td> por cada celda.
            var celda = document.createElement("td");
            //Creamos el elemento <img> al cual asociamos el atributo de la ruta de la imagen.
            var imagenAnimal = document.createElement("img");
            imagenAnimal.setAttribute("src", "./images/"+animales[contador]+".png");    
            //Creamos el elemento <audio> al cual asociamos un elemento <source>.
            var audioAnimal = document.createElement("audio");
            var sourceAnimal = document.createElement("source");
            sourceAnimal.setAttribute("src", "./sounds/"+animales[contador]+".wav");
            sourceAnimal.setAttribute("type", "audio/wav");
            //Al audioAnimal le añadimos el sourceAnimal.
            audioAnimal.appendChild(sourceAnimal);
            //Creamos el elemento <div> para cada animal al cual asociamos un id y una clase.
            var divAnimal = document.createElement("div"); 
            divAnimal.setAttribute("id", animales[contador]);           
            divAnimal.setAttribute("class", "animal");
            //Al divAnimal le añadimos la imagen del animal.
            divAnimal.appendChild(imagenAnimal);
            //A la celda le añadimos el divAnimal.
            celda.appendChild(divAnimal); 
            //A la hilera "tr" le añadimos la celda "td".
            hilera.appendChild(celda);
            contador++;
        } 
        //Agrega la hilera al final de la tabla (al final del elemento tblbody). 
        tblBody.appendChild(hilera); 
    }

    //Posiciona el <tbody> debajo del elemento <table>.
    tabla.appendChild(tblBody);
    //appends <table> into <body>.
    div.appendChild(tabla);
    //Modifica el atributo "border" de la tabla y lo fija a "2";
    tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}


/*Función para lanzar el sonido del cerdo.*/
function sonidoCerdo() {
    alert('CERDO');
}
//Asignar la función externa al elemento con id=cerdo.
document.getElementById("cerdo").onclick = sonidoCerdo;


/*Función para lanzar el sonido del cerdo.*/
function sonidoGato() {
    alert('GATO');
}
//Asignar la función externa al elemento con id=gato.
document.getElementById("gato").onclick = sonidoGato;


/*Función para lanzar el sonido del perro.*/
function sonidoPerro() {
    alert('PERRO');
}
//Asignar la función externa al elemento con id=perro.
document.getElementById("perro").onclick = sonidoPerro;


/*Función para lanzar el sonido del vaca.*/
function sonidoVaca() {
    alert('VACA');
}
//Asignar la función externa al elemento con id=vaca.
document.getElementById("vaca").onclick = sonidoVaca;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomendaria que hicieras

```
window.onload = function(){
    crearTabla();
    function sonidoCerdo() {
       alert('CERDO');
    }
    //Asignar la función externa al elemento con id=cerdo.
    document.getElementById("cerdo").onclick = sonidoCerdo;
}
```

De esta manera, se cargara el elemento y luego se le asignara la funcion, recuerda que todo codigo Javascript debe ejecutarse despues de cargar el DOM.

Comment: De acuerdo sí, es una opción englobarlo todo al recargar la página aunque los eventos no harían falta pero sí sería una buena práctica. Lo modifico ahora mismo.

Comment: ¿Entonces se debía a que intentaba acceder al elemento id=cerdo sin estar creado previamente, debido a que ejecutaba después crearTabla? Qué extraño: debido a que puse window.onload=crearTabla;

Comment: Si, sin embargo, las funciones estaban declaradas fuera del `onload`, el proceso de ejecución seguia su curso y probablemente no estaba creado aun, podrias debugear dejando tu codigo tal como estaba e imprimir `document.getElementById("cerdo")`

Comment: Haré un console.log(cerdo) donde var cerdo=document.getElementById("cerdo");

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración.